# Refactor this Ruby and Rails code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this model:

```
class Event < Registration
  serialize :fields, Hash
  Activities=['Annonce', 'Butiksaktivitet', 'Salgskonkurrence']

  CUSTOM_FIELDS=[:activity, :description, :date_from, :date_to, :budget_pieces, :budget_amount, :actual_pieces, :actual_amount]
  attr_accessor *CUSTOM_FIELDS

  before_save :gather_fields
  after_find :distribute_fields

  private

  def gather_fields
    self.fields={}
    CUSTOM_FIELDS.each do |cf|
      self.fields[cf]=eval("self.#{cf.to_s}")
    end
  end

  def distribute_fields
    unless self.fields.nil?
      self.fields.each do |k,v|
        eval("self.#{k.to_s}=v") 
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I have a feeling that this can be done shorter and more elegant. Does anyone have an idea?

- Jacob

BTW. Can anyone tell me what the asterisk in front of CUSTOM_FIELDS does? I know what it does in a method definition (def foo(*args)) but not here...

Comment: I think this question fits better in codereview (http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ - the beta is now active!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright first off: **never `10000000000.times { puts "ever" }` use `eval`** when you don't know what you're doing. It is the nuclear bomb of the Ruby world in the way that it can wreak devestation across a wide area, causing similar symptoms to radiation poisoning throughout your code. Just don't.

With that in mind:

```
class Event < Registration
  serialize :fields, Hash
  Activities = ['Annonce', 'Butiksaktivitet', 'Salgskonkurrence']

  CUSTOM_FIELDS = [:activity, 
                 :description,
                 :date_from,
                 :date_to,
                 :budget_pieces,
                 :budget_amount,
                 :actual_pieces,
                 :actual_amount] #1
  attr_accessor *CUSTOM_FIELDS #2

  before_save :gather_fields
  after_find :distribute_fields

  private

  def gather_fields
    CUSTOM_FIELDS.each do |cf|
      self.fields[cf] = send(cf) #3
    end
  end

  def distribute_fields
    unless self.fields.empty?
      self.fields.each do |k,v|
        send("#{k.to_s}=", v) #3
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Now for some notes:

1. By putting each custom field on its own line, you increase code readability. I don't want to have to scroll to the end of the line to read all the possible custom fields or to add my own.
2. The `*CUSTOM_FIELDS` passed into `attr_accessor` uses what is referred to as the "splat operator". By calling it in this way, the elements of the `CUSTOM_FIELDS` array will be passed as individual arguments to the `attr_accessor` method rather than as one (the array itself)
3. Finally, we use the `send` method to call methods we don't know the names of during programming, rather than the evil `eval`.

Other than that, I cannot find anything else to refactor about this code.

Comment: Thanks so much for your solution. I promise that I won't use eval ever again (almost :-)).

Answer (score 1):

I agree with previous posters. In addition I would probably move the gather_fields and distribute_fields methods to the parent model to avoid having to repeat the code in every child model.

```
class Registration < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...

protected
  def gather_fields(custom_fields)
    custom_fields.each do |cf|
      self.fields[cf] = send(cf)
    end
  end

  def distribute_fields
    unless self.fields.empty?
      self.fields.each do |k,v|
        send("#{k.to_s}=", v)
      end
    end
  end
end

class Event < Registration
  ...

  before_save :gather_fields
  after_find :distribute_fields

private
  def gather_fields(custom_fields = CUSTOM_FIELDS)
    super
  end
end
```

Comment: Great - you are so right! I have implemented that - I am wondering. Can I do something like send("#{k.to_s}=", v) if attr_defined?(k). That way the code won't blow up if the attribute isn't defined for the class...

Comment: Yes, either that or you could send custom_fields to that method as well and loop through them instead of self.fields

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the two evals with send calls:

```
self.fields[cf] = self.send(cf.to_s)


self.send("#{k}=", v)
```

"#{}" does a to_s, so you don't need k.to_s

Activities, being a constant, should probably be ACTIVITIES.

Answer (score 0):

For that asterisk *, check out this post: [What is the splat/unary/asterisk operator useful for?](http://raflabs.com/blogs/silence-is-foo/2010/08/07/ruby-idioms-what-is-the-splatunary-operator-useful-for/)

```
Activities=['Annonce', 'Butiksaktivitet', 'Salgskonkurrence']
```

can be written: `ACTIVITIES = %w(Annonce, Butiksaktivitet, Salgskonkurrence).freeze` since you are defining a constant.

```
def distribute_fields
  unless self.fields.empty?
    self.fields.each do |k,v|
      send("#{k.to_s}=", v) #3
    end
  end
end
```

can be written as a one liner:

```
def distribute_fields 
  self.fields.each { |k,v| send("#{k.to_s}=", v) } unless self.fields.empty?
end
```

Ryan Bigg, gave a good answer.